# How do we see an image if converges behind us?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

Say we have a concave mirror which is converging light rays from you at a distance $v$ from the mirror where $v>u$. ($u$ is the distance of you from the mirror). So if the light is converging behind us, can we still see an image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can *always* see yourself in the concave mirror with your own eyes (if that is called *seeing your image*) because the eyes will adjust to the distance of the object you're focusing on.
However, if it is a question of principle about being able to see an object when the image of it does not converge at the point you're observing it from, then you'd see a blurred image nonetheless. That is because the rays of light from different parts of the object are not in the correct relative positions to one another with respect to their points of emissions from the object.